# Unlock bootloader for Lenovo A1000-T

Tags: rooting, bootloader, fastboot, lenovo

How did you go into fastboot mode? I am not able to figure out.

```
adb reboot bootloader
adb reboot-bootloader
adb reboot fastboot
```

None of them worked, However

```
adb reboot recovery
```

opens it in recovery mode. I have installed Lenovo Le Tools also.
Also tried to open it by pressing -

```
Vol down + Power (opens factory mode)
Vol up + Power (opens recovery mode)
```

Note - I have learnt that MediaTek devices doesn't have fastboot mode. I am trying to flash Ubuntu Mobile on my tab which first requires "OEM unlock" which can be done in fastboot mode but if it doesn't have fastboot mode then what's the alternative way?
Please help!

Comment: Your device isn't in [the list of officially and unofficially supported devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices), so I don't think you'll be able to install Ubuntu on it anyway. We can't help with the Ubuntu side of things here, though.

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks for commenting. My question is regarding bootloader. How to get it unlocked? Ububtu mobile is secondary thing.

Comment: Well developer options has bootloader unlocker (OEM Unlocking) I dont no how to use it but you might know If not contact your device manager.